# JavaScript reduce with Promises not returning sequentially

Tags: javascript, promise, reduce

For some reason all the functions are returning at the same time.

I want to wait for the first function to resolve then call `_done()` before calling the second function, and then call `_done()` then call the third function and then call `_done()`again.

Each time `_done()` is called I want to pass the values that have resolved from the previous function call.

The working demo is here https://repl.it/MeHl/9

```
"use-strict"

function _test(actions){
    return actions.reduce((chain, action) => {
      const func = this[action.functionToCall](action.argumentToSend);
      return chain.then(() => func()).then(val => console.log(val));
    }, Promise.resolve().then(val => _done()));
}

function _one(data){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(function(){  
        console.log(data); 
        resolve();
      }, 2000);
    })
}

function _two(data){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function(){  
          console.log(data); 
          resolve();
        }, 2000);
    })
}

function _three(data){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(function(){  
          console.log(data); 
          resolve();
        }, 2000);
    })
}

function _done(data){
  console.log(data);
}

const arrayOfObjects = [
    { functionToCall: '_one', argumentToSend: 'Yay function one was called with this argument' },
    { functionToCall: '_two', argumentToSend: 'Yay function two was called with this argument' },
    { functionToCall: '_three', argumentToSend: 'Yay function three was called with this argument' },
    ];

_test(arrayOfObjects);
```

So the log should look like

```
Yay function one was called with this argument
resolvedFromOne
Yay function two was called with this argument
resolvedFromTwo
Yay function three was called with this argument
resolvedFromThree
```

Comment: `const func = this[action.functionToCall](action.argumentToSend);` already calls the function. I'm sure this is not what you had in mind.

Comment: how does your code expect `resolvedFromOne/Two/Three` to be logged?

Comment: the way to get what you expect is like https://jsfiddle.net/LoL119ep/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code produces the expected output

```js
    function _test(actions){
        return actions.reduce((chain, action) => {
          return chain.then(() => action.functionToCall(action.argumentToSend)).then(val => console.log(val));
        }, Promise.resolve());
    }
    
    function _one(data){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(function(){  
            console.log(data); 
            resolve('resolvedFromOne');
          }, 2000);
        })
    }
    
    function _two(data){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function(){  
              console.log(data); 
              resolve('resolvedFromTwo');
            }, 2000);
        })
    }
    
    function _three(data){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            setTimeout(function(){  
              console.log(data); 
              resolve('resolvedFromThree');
            }, 2000);
        })
    }
    
    // not required
    function _done(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
    
    const arrayOfObjects = [
        { functionToCall: _one, argumentToSend: 'Yay function one was called with this argument' },
        { functionToCall: _two, argumentToSend: 'Yay function two was called with this argument' },
        { functionToCall: _three, argumentToSend: 'Yay function three was called with this argument' },
        ];
    
    _test(arrayOfObjects);
```